# Cheap PC with 8GB of RAM

Tags: desktop, memory, server, mini-pc

I'm looking to purchase a PC to run my Minecraft server on. It needs 8GB of RAM and a decent processor. I'm not going to do much else with it, so I don't need a large HDD or an SSD.

Ideally, the price would be under £200, or even under £150 if possible. If there's a good PC with 4GB of RAM and another cheap 4GB stick, that would work too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking just for a PC without a monitor,speakers, keyboard...(considering you have those). Budget might go bit over the 270$ limit. [This](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/jCtPZ8) would be a perfect PC. You can also buy these parts used or new for less money since the pricing here is Amazon/Newegg-based. I figured you wouldn't need an OS(since everyone knows where to get it :D) and an optical drive.

Comment: You need to use the permalink to share lists.

Comment: Edited! Thanks for letting letting me know about that